# Is there any way to make buttons and windows transparent in AppleScript?

Tags: xcode, applescript, applescript-objc

I would like to know if there is a simple way to do this, I tried some things I saw searching on google but it did not work.

```
tell window "Window"
                set opaque to false
                set alpha value to 0.5
            end tell
```

Comment: Indeed, it is always useful to know that you tried "some things", even though they didn't work.  But it's much more useful to know what those things were, as it gives us an idea of what you're trying to achieve, and provides a reference point from where to start.  Right now, your question is quite broad, so showing us what you tried will also help focus the topic to a set of key issues you experienced in your attempts, and demonstrate what sort of level of understanding you're at so you receive an answer that you can make sense of.

Comment: @CJK, You're correct, thank you!

Comment: From your code snippet, it seems like you wish to take some `window` object that presumably belongs to some application, such as _Safari_, and adjust its opacity.  Am I understanding you correctly ?  If so, it's not possible, as far as I am aware.  I believe one may only have control over a window's appearance if it's a window that your script created, i.e. by way of ASObjC.  Perhaps I'm mistaken and someone will correct me, but I do know that opacity isn't a property that exists for `window` objects in vanilla AppleScript.

Comment: thanks for the information @CJK

Comment: You're welcome. Consider selecting the answer by @user3439894 below, because it's correct as far as each of us know, and will assist other users who come looking for an answer to this same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, *basic standard* **AppleScript**, by itself, doesn't have the *commands* to make buttons and windows transparent.

I'd look into using **AppleScriptObjC** and see if it's possible there.